# Iterate through sub items in JADE

Tags: json, pug

I'm trying to iterate through sub items in a JSON file using "each" in JADE, but it keeps saying "can't read property 'length' of undefined"

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c33438d3d1e1323111fce6e"),
    "title" : "Nieuws",
    "__v" : 0,
    "subitem" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "subitem1"
        }, 
        {
            "title" : "subitem2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to reach the 2 subitems and iterate through these with:

```
each item in data.subitem
  p #{item.title}
```

in JADE

Comment: You have no "data" element in the model you shown. Did you try `each item in subitem`? It seems to me that `data` is in fact undefined (and attending to what you posted it seems that this is the case...).